# Por que window.innerHeight/ window.innerWindow nao funciona com document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas

Por que isso nao funciona?

```
const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight
```

E isso sim?

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você usa o `querySelector`, ele retorna o primeiro elemento correspondente, por isso você consegue alterar as propriedades, já no primeiro caso, como mencionado na outra resposta, ele retorna uma lista de elementos, e o acesso é feito por meio do índice.

```
 const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Answer (score 3):

Porque `getElementsByTagName` retorna uma lista de elementos, se você quer pegar alguma propriedade do primeiro elemento, tem que usar:

```
const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
canvas[0].width = window.innerWidth;
canvas[0].height = window.innerHeight;
```

Ou

```
const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```